# [] operator not supported for strings, but is array?

Tags: php, arrays

I've got several config files, and I'm trying to add them together by including them all in my script.

This returns an error `[] operator not supported for strings`, but `$config` is not a string?

I've tried declaring my array first like `$config = [];` and `$config = array();`, with no luck.

**File:** config1.php

```
$config[] = array(
    'database' => array(
        'name' => 'test'
    )
);
```

**File:** config2.php

```
$config[] = array(
    'sarCallbacks' => array(
        'test1',
        'test2',
        'test3'
    )
);
```

If I put the array key in the `$config` index, it gets even worse.

What am I doing wrong?

*Note: I'm running PHP 5.5.9.*

Comment: What version of PHP are you running?

Comment: have you tried defining it with `array()`

Comment: What line generates that error?

Comment: Are you certain you're not assigning `$config` as a string somewhere?

Comment: ... and that's the only possible explanation.

Comment: Of course it exists. `PHP` has lexical scope, not block scope.

Comment: @KidDiamond no, it will override the value `$config`, using `foreach()` doesn't change the scope :)

Comment: Even if you don't assign anything to `$config` inside the foreach loop, it will override with the value of the last iteration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you mentioned in your comments, you're reusing the variable name `$config` within a `foreach()` loop, which overrides `$config` (control structures do not create a local scope). The value of `$config` then becomes the last value in your looped array, which is a string. You're then trying to append array elements to that string, resulting in the error above.

> "The scope of a variable is the context within which it is defined.
>   For the most part all PHP variables only have a single scope."

http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Answer (score 3):

For PHP <= 5.3 it is

```
$config = array();
```

The new short-array-syntax `$config = [];` is for PHP5.4+ as documented in the PHP docs.

Comment: "_Note: I'm running PHP 5.5.9._"

Comment: @mark Not actually true. His code works fine in 5.2.9 and 5.3.22 and 5.5.9